# arduino error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

I am new to arduino and C++ and am running into the above error.  It seems pretty self-explanatory, however I can't find the missing comma within the code.  The code worked fine before I added the `binaryOut` function so I believe it is in there.

It would be nice if Arduino gave an indication of where the error is occurring.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#define ultrasonic 6
#define buzzer 3
#define latchPin 8
#define clockPin 12
#define dataPin 11

int sound = 250;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(latchPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clockPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dataPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
  long duration, inches;

  pinMode(ultrasonic, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ultrasonic, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(ultrasonic, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(ultrasonic, LOW);

  pinMode(ultrasonic, INPUT);
  duration = pulseIn(ultrasonic, HIGH);
  inches = microsecondsToInches(duration);

  if(inches > 36 || inches <= 0){
    Serial.print("Out of range. ");
    Serial.println(inches);
  }else{
   Serial.print(inches);
   Serial.println(" in.");
  }
  binaryOut(inches);
  digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
}

long microsecondsToInches(long microseconds){
  /* 73.746 microseconds per inch
  * Sound travels at 1130 ft/s */
  return microseconds/73.746/2;
}

void binaryOut(byte dataOut){
  Serial.println(dataOut);
  boolean pinState;
  for(int i = 0; i <= 7; i++){
    digitalWrite(clockPin, LOW);
    if(dataOut & (1<<i)){
      pinState = HIGH;
    }else{
      pinState = LOW;
    }
    digitalWrite(dataPin, pinState);
    digitalWrite(clockPin, HIGH);
  }
  digitalWrite(clockPin, LOW);
}
```

EDIT: in Arduino HIGH and LOW are defined constants (http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Constants) and boolean is a primitive data type (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type)

EDIT2: I modeled the `binaryOut` from the example (`shiftOut`) in the image below.
[image]

EDIT3: The exact error is:

```
In file included from UltrasonicRangeSensorAJ.ino:7:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino/Arduino.h:111: error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino/Arduino.h:112: error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant
```

I initially thought the "111" and "112" corresponded to the line number but my code has less than 90 lines.

Comment: Full error message where?

Comment: I think that we need more information on this.  There are constants that are used, but not defined in your sample (boolean, byte, LOW, HIGH, etc).  Knowing those constants may help.  Also, `inches` is defined as a long, but you are passing it to `binaryOut`, which is expecting a `byte`.  Data loss may occur.  If the error message really included "...", then I would lean towards it being an issue with the function definition, as the only place I know of in C that uses "..." is defining a variadic function.

Comment: @Velox, I edited the post to answer some of your questions.  Please let me know if there is anything else.

Comment: As @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams said, you should include the full error message, as this will state the line number where the error occurs.

Comment: Have you tried changing `Serial.println(dataOut);` to `Serial.print(dataOut);`?  It looks like `println` is designed for strings, and `dataOut` is a byte.

Comment: 'println' adds a new line character after the text or variable is printed (http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Println)

Comment: Did you notice how the error message isn't pointing to your source code?

Comment: The files in the error message.

Comment: I found the files.  How could I have diagnosed the error initially and found the problem?  Would it be in the ".H" file?

Comment: It would be in the file listed in the error message. Or at least you would be closer to finding it

Comment: Move this question to Arduino SE (arduino.stackexchange.com)

Comment: flagged to mod with request to move.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Arduino libraries use the "dataPin" and "clockPin" identifiers for their own purposes. By defining them with actual values in your code you've caused the Arduino code to become uncompilable. Rename them.

> ```
> void shiftOut(uint8_t dataPin, uint8_t clockPin, uint8_t bitOrder, uint8_t val);
> uint8_t shiftIn(uint8_t dataPin, uint8_t clockPin, uint8_t bitOrder);
> ```

Comment: That was it. Oddly, the book I have also labeled them "dataPin" and "clockPin" which is why I thought it was safe.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is just for record purpose.

I found this example http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/PlayMelody?action=sourceblock&num=1 to play melody.

Below lines in the example code also throws me the same error **expected ',' or '…' before numeric constant**

```
#define  c     3830    // 261 Hz 
#define  d     3400    // 294 Hz 
#define  e     3038    // 329 Hz
```

But when I modified above lines something like this(below) works fine.

```
#define  C     3830    // 261 Hz 
#define  D     3400    // 294 Hz 
#define  E     3038    // 329 Hz
```

while defining you can't use lower case single letter.

Comment: That is good to note.  I know the accepted syntax for constants is to write them in all caps but didn't know you would receive an error for starting the constant name in lower case.

Comment: But this happens only for lowercase single letter.
  #define  cc     3830 // This works fine